# Como verificar uma senha encriptada em php?

Tags: hash

Bom dia..

Tentei fazer um hash usando password_hash do php e nao obtive sucesso, ele até gera a hash, porem o problema está na hora de verificar a hash. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Função Login e Create

```
   public function login($email,$senha){

  $query = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email= :email AND senha= :senha");
  $query->bindValue(':email', $email);
  $query->bindValue(':senha', $senha);
  $execute = $query->execute();
  if($execute){

    $fetch = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    if(count($fetch)>0){

       $q = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email= :email AND senha= :senha");
       $q->bindValue(':email', $email);
       $q->bindValue(':senha', $senha);
       $q->execute();
       $fetch = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);


       $_SESSION['USER'] = (array)$fetch;

       return true;

    }else{
      return false;
    }

  }else{
    return false;
  }
```

}

public function create($email,$senha,$whatsapp,$nome){

```
 $query = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (nome,email,whatsapp,senha) VALUES (:nome,:email,:whatsapp,:senha) ");
 $query->bindValue(':nome', $nome);
 $query->bindValue(':email', $email);
 $query->bindValue(':whatsapp', $whatsapp);
 $query->bindValue(':senha', $senha);

 if($query->execute()){
   return true;
 }else{
   return false;
 }
```

}

Aqui a parte de criar usuario com hash

```
  if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['whatsapp']) && isset($_POST['senha']) && isset($_POST['nome'])){



$email    = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$senha    = password_hash($_POST['senha'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$whatsapp = $_POST['whatsapp'];
$nome     = $_POST['nome'];


if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo '{"erro":true,"create":0,"login":0,"msg":"Email inválido, verifique-o."}';
    exit;
}

if(!is_numeric($whatsapp)){
        echo '{"erro":true,"create":0,"login":0,"msg":"Tefone inválido, verifique o número."}';
    exit;
}
    
if ($nome === '') {
        echo '{"erro":true,"create":0,"login":0,"msg":"Por favor, Preencha o nome."}';
    exit;
}

if ($whatsapp === '') {
        echo '{"erro":true,"create":0,"login":0,"msg":"Por favor, Preencha o telefone."}';
    exit;
}

if ($email === '') {
        echo '{"erro":true,"create":0,"login":0,"msg":"Por favor, Preencha o email."}';
    exit;
}

if ($senha === '') {
        echo '{"erro":true,"create":0,"login":0,"msg":"Por favor, Preencha a senha."}';
    exit;
}

$verify = $clientes->verify_email($email);

if ($verify > 0) {
        echo '{"erro":true,"create":0,"login":0,"msg":"Este endereço de e-mail já está sendo usado por outro usuário."}';
    exit;
}

  $create = $clientes->create($email,$senha,$whatsapp,$nome);

  if($create){
    $login = $clientes->login($email,$senha);
    if($login){
      echo '{"erro":false,"create":1,"login":1,"msg":"logado"}';
    }else{
      echo '{"erro":true,"create":1,"login":0,"msg":"Sua conta foi criada, faça login"}';
    }
  }else{
    echo '{"erro":true,"create":0,"login":0,"msg":"Erro temporario, tente mais tarde, ou entre em contato com o suporte"}';
  }
```

}

Aqui a parte de login

```
  if(isset($_POST['email'])){

$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

$login = $clientes->login($email,$senha);

if($login){

  if(isset($_SESSION['checkout'])){
    echo '3';
  }else{
    echo '1';
  }

}else{
  echo '0';
}
```

}

OBS: A parte de verificar não coloquei ai pq todo jeito que tentei da erro de login.

Answer (score 1):

Basta ver a documentação, em https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php:

> `password_verify ( string $password , string $hash ) : bool`
> Verifies that the given hash matches the given password.

---

O seu `$query = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email= :email AND senha= :senha")` nunca vai funcionar por motivos óbvios.

O  `senha= :senha` nunca dará certo. *Na verdade, ele pode até dar certo, mas não será utilizando o `password_verify`. Para ele funcionar sem o `password_verify` precisaria, de qualquer forma, obter o exato mesmo salt utilizado e utilizar o `password_hash` com o mesmo salt e algoritmo. Então, esquece, e assuma que "não dará certo" pois há uma forma melhor.*

---

Para usar o `password_verify` você precisa pegar o usuário pelo o e-mail e então utilizar a comparação de senha, usando o password_verify.

Em resumo imagine o seguinte:

```
$db = SELECT kdf_da_senha FROM tabela WHERE usuario = email@provedor.com;
$form = $_POST;

if $db[kdf_da_senha] == $form["senha"] {
  // Senha correta
}
```

Basicamente, é isso que irá fazer:

```
public function login($email,$senha){

  // Busca pelo e-mail
  $query = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email= :email");
  $query->bindValue(':email', $email);
  $execute = $query->execute();
  if(!$execute){
     return false;
  }

  // Pega a senha (...)
  $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  if(!is_array($result)){
     return false;
  }

  // Compara a senha
  if(!password_verify($senha, $result["senha"])) {
    return false;
  }

  // Se tudo der certo, set a $result:
  $_SESSION['USER'] = $result;
  return true;
}
```

A idea é a mesma mencionada. Primeiro, pega as informações baseado no `email`, depois compara a senha do banco de dados (que foi criado com o `password_hash`) com a senha que o usuário ofereceu.

---

**Note que este código assume que o e-mail é único. Se ele não for único (podendo haver duplicidade), você terá que fazer um loop para cada senha e compara-lo (usando o `password_verify` para cada registro com o mesmo e-mail).**

Comment: PS: O código não está testado e pode conter algum erro. _Não tenho como testar, uma vez que não utilizo mais PHP, e não tenho ele instalado._

Comment: Obrigado, testei o código, deu erro na rowCount. Removi e autenticou, existe algum problema de remover o count?

Comment: Vendo a documentação, o `rowCount` do PDO não é igual ao `numRows` do MySQLi, não há garantias que funciona sempre no SELECT em todos os bancos de dados. Não há problema em remove-lo, entretanto, é importante saber se existe algum registro ou não. Eu alterei o código para ` if(!is_array($result)){  return false; }`, na esperança de funcionar, mas é chute.

Comment: perfeito. Muito obrigado

Comment: Parece que fecharam a pergunta, não consigo marcar a melhor resposta